# Difference between object oriented and object based programming language

Tags: javascript, java

What's the difference between object based and object oriented programming language?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Object oriented programming languages follow all concepts belonging to OOP. Object-based language doesn't support all the features of OOPs like Polymorphism and Inheritance Object-based language has in-built object like JavaScript has window object. Object-based languages are JavaScript.